# How resize Table view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

Actually I have 4 view attached to a single view, only one view is visible at one tym. when i click a button to go to next view, present view is hidden and next view is appeared.

I have 1 table view in each subview.
I have 1 row @ first view, 5 rows @ second view, and 2 rows @ third view and forth view has no table view.

now the problem is when I switch to next view the older content of table-view does not disappear instantly.

On differentiating Cell-identifier also table view is messed up and all contents of view are shown at all time.

Can anybody suggest how to reload table View so that all the rows of all view not messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [tableView reloadData] when you switch between views

Comment: ya i was using it, but via same object. Problem is solved by creating seperate objects of table view.